# 3rd argument of python range

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list of lists using a list comprehension method. I found this solution online:

```
output = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[output[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(output), 2)]
```

This is the first time I have come across a 3rd argument in range, What does the 3rd argument of range do?

Comment: per the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range). It is the step.

Comment: what does a step mean? @idjaw

Comment: @e_mam106 Open up an interpreter and play around with it.

Comment: Have you played around with the output to see what happens when you play with that number? Go to your interpreter and do a simple example `for i in range(0, 10, 2)` and print out the `i`. Then change the third argument to a 3. and try again.

Comment: This was asked in 2015 and _still_ downvoted. Please do a little research.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ congrats ;)

Comment: @idjaw What for? :o Finding a dupe?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think I just noticed now you had the hammer. :P

Comment: @idjaw Lol.. I've had it for I think a week now? xD Got it before you, I think

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument of range is the stepping, meaning how much to increment the last value for:

```
>>> for i in range (0,10,2):
...     print i
0
2
4
6
8
```